# How to have more controls over the borderColor per arc segment for chart.js pie charts

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I do have the following requirements for a pie chart

- have a certain number of "visible" segments (e.g. 4 segments with a black border color)
- have a higher number of segments (e.g 40) without a white border color so that I can set their background color in a flexible way (when clicking on one of those segments I want to set the background color for all segments starting from 0° till the clicked segment.)

I think I have two options to solve this requirement

- I could render two charts with the same size above each other (the chart in the background with less segments with visible borders and the the chart with non visible borders in the foreground)
- or if it would be possible to have more control about the border color of the arcs - then I could make the outer part black, the left part white and the right part black for some of the segments. See image for example of an arc with different colors

[image: arc with different colors]

The following screenshot shows what I achieved using two datasets - the inner dataset with 2 segments, the outer dataset with 4 segments, no border color. I'd be happy now if the two datasets would be displayed on top of each other :)

[image: Two datasets]

I've found similar questions:

- [How to customize border style on Chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107172/how-to-customize-border-style-on-chart-js) - I guess that could work for customize the arc rendering as well but I have no idea how to do it
- [Chartjs pie chart out side border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61502108/chartjs-pie-chart-out-side-border) - basically what I need but unfortunately with no solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to put two charts on top of each other with the help of [How can I stack two same-sized canvas on top of each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037649/how-can-i-stack-two-same-sized-canvas-on-top-of-each-other) :)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas2" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}

.wrapper canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Javascript:

```
dataInner = {
    datasets: [{
        data: [10, 10, 10, 10,10, 10],        
            borderWidth:0,
        backgroundColor: ['blue', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white']
    }] 
};

optionsOuter = {
    events: ['click'],          
  // change the background color of the "inner chart" depending on the clicked segment
  onClick: function(evt){
    var activePoints = myInnerPieChart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
    // check if the was possible to determine the active point, if not return
    if (typeof activePoints === 'undefined' || activePoints.length <1) return;
    var selectedIndex = activePoints[0]._index;
    
    // change the background color of all arcs till the selected index    
    var tmp_data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myInnerPieChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor.length; i++) {
      if (i <= selectedIndex){
        tmp_data.push('blue');                                              
      }
      else{
        tmp_data.push('white'); // same color as "bar_fill" css class
      }
    }   
    
    myInnerPieChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = tmp_data;
    myInnerPieChart.update();
  } 

}

dataOuter = {
    datasets: [{
        data: [10, 10],        
            borderWidth:1,
        borderColor: ['black', 'black']
    }] 
};


var myInnerPieChart = new Chart($('#canvas1'), {
    type: 'pie',
    data: dataInner
});

var myOuterPieChart = new Chart($('#canvas2'), {
    type: 'pie',
    data: dataOuter,
    options: optionsOuter
});
```

It looks like this and I think this should help to achieve my requirements: https://jsfiddle.net/xuce274p/3/